# How to compare a value in struct using match

Tags: rust

I would like to replace my `if` case with `match` case

```
struct Point {
    x: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let p = Point { x: 0 };
    let q = Point { x: 0 };
    
    if p.x == q.x {
        println!("p and q have same x: {0}", p.x);
    } else {
        println!("p and q doesn't have same x value");
    }
    
    // match p.x {
    //     q.x => println!("p and q have same x: {0}", p.x),
    //     _ => println!("On neither axis"),
    // }
}
```

which run normally. However when I uncomment my code snippet in the code an error would occur.

```
error: expected one of `,`, `=>`, `@`, `if`, `|`, or `}`, found `.`
  --> src/main.rs:16:10
   |
16 |         q.x => println!("p and q have same x: {0}", p.x),
   |          ^ expected one of `,`, `=>`, `@`, `if`, `|`, or `}`
```

Not sure how to fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only `const` values can be compared, and there is no way to transform a non-`const` variable into `const`. However, a guard expression can be used.

```rust
match p.x {
    v if p.x == q.x => println!("p and q have same x: {0}", v),
    _ => println!("On neither axis"),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very slight variation on Paisins answer where the Point struct is Destructured in the match

```
match p {
    Point {x} if x == q.x => println!("p and q have the same x: {x}"),
    _ => println!("On neither axis"),
}
```

Comment: Just for completeness, you can also destructure both `p` and `q` with `match (p, q) { (Point { x: px },  Point { x: qx }) if px == qx => ... }`. This would move `p` and `q` into the tuple, though, at least if they are not `Copy`, so they'll be gone after the `match` expression.